# how to add popup window hyperlink into javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, html, popupwindow

I am trying to place a popup window hyper link inside javascript variable but when i outputh the result to div the hyperlink doesn't(when clicking on it) open and got wrong url! could any one show me how to fix this problem.Thanks

```
  var siteContents2 = "<li>"
+"<a href='javascript:window.open('http://awebsite.com/static/flash/ok1234567890123445.swf?itemid="+itemName+", 'yourWindowName', 'width=200,height=150')'>"+itemName+"</a>";
```

the hyperlink produced inside div which doesn't open and got wrong url!:

```
   <a href="javascript:window.open(" 'http:="" awebsite.com="" static="" flash="" ok1234567890123445.swf?itemid="pen" ,="" 'yourwindowname',="" 'width="200,height=150')'">pen</a>

document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML += siteContents2;
```

Answer (score 3):

You quote terminations was not proper

```
var siteContents2 = "<li>"
+"<a href=\"javascript:window.open('http://awebsite.com/static/flash/ok1234567890123445.swf?itemid="+itemName+"', 'yourWindowName', 'width=200,height=150')\">"+itemName+"</a>";
```

Comment: thanks for reply. But still it seperates the urls parts and it has missing slashes in url!

Comment: then there some other problem also

Comment: arun can you check this fiddle it would be good if you help me fix it.The second test is not poping up and & changes to "&amp;" .How to make & with "amp;"?jsfiddle.net/2nR6g

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 var siteContents2 =    "<li>"
    +"<a href=\"javascript:window.open('http://awebsite.com/static/flash/ok1234567890123445.swf?itemid="+itemName+"', 'yourWindowName', 'width=200,height=150')\">"+itemName+"</a>";




<a href=\"......................\">
```